# Snippet to get all local classes from a module

Tags: python, object-oriented, python-3.x, reflection, modules

I'm working on a project which due to the complexity of the business logic has had to pull out some classes to do computation related to some values in a database. To link the code and database, both when inserting and selecting, I need to get a list of all the class names contained within a single file. It works for me, but is this a sane approach?

```
import inspect

import my_module

my_module_class_names = [
    name for name, clazz in inspect.getmembers(my_module, inspect.isclass)
    if clazz.__module__ == my_module.__name__
]
```

- `inspect.getmembers(my_module, inspect.isclass)` gets any class members of `my_module`.
- `if clazz.__module__ == my_module.__name__` ensures that classes `import`ed into `my_module` are *excluded* from the list. This is the main reason I'm asking for a review - I only thought to include this clause because I had already `import`ed other classes, and therefore the list had extraneous members.

Alternatively, from within `my_module`:

```
import inspect
import sys

def class_names() -> List[str]:
    return [
        name for name, clazz in inspect.getmembers(sys.modules[__name__], inspect.isclass)
        if clazz.__module__ == sys.modules[__name__].__name__
    ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have already used similar code and it looks rather fine. Some nitpicks:

- I’d name the variable `cls` to mimic the name often used as first parameters of `@classmethod`s; or `class_` as it is more common;
- I’d store a list of classes intead of a list of names, this feels more directly usable (and names are still stored as `cls.__name__` if need be);
- `sys.modules[__name__].__name__` should be just `__name__`.

---

Alternatively, since these classes seems related to each other, you may have an inheritance tree; or maybe a common base class. In this case, you could be even more specific using something such as:

```
[cls for _, cls in inspect.getmembers(my_module, inspect.isclass) if issubclass(cls, my_module.CommonBase)]
```

or

```
my_module.CommonBase.__subclasses__()
```

if there really is a single level of inheritance, but I wouldn't count much on it as it can break so easily.

Comment: Excellent! I do need the actual class names rather than the `type`s, and I don't have a class hierarchy, but this can serve as basically a recipe for anyone who wants either variant of this pattern.